# two comboboxes in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, sqldatareader

i am delaeaing with comboboxes in datagridview in windowsforms 
assume that i  have two combboxes in one datagridview so my question is
how to populate comboboxcolumn in datagridview according to selected values from another comboboxcolum in this datagridview

Comment: do you mean that you have two combobox columns for each row in the grid?

Comment: please answer because this question is urgent thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I am kind of late to this, but what you should do is attach a value changed event handler to your columns. The handler should trigger when you select a new value, then you use the arguments passed to the function to determine which row was altered and change the second combo box in the row. I'd provide an example, but I am almost sure you wont be coming back to look at this answer anyway.

Edit:
didn't think you would really comeback for this, but here is one way to implement dynamic ComboBoxes. I can't say I am completely proud of this answer however because it does not work with databinding (you will have to add each row yourself and set the proper initial values.) but at least this solution can point you towards either the right direction or a new one.

```
public partial class DualComboBoxGridViewForm : Form
{
    private Dictionary<Country, List<City>> locations;

    public DualComboBoxGridViewForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeLocations();

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    }

    private void InitializeLocations()
    {
        // Loading these from a database would be highly recommended, I 
        // just did it like this with a dictionary to it would be easier 
        // to show.
        locations = new Dictionary<Country, List<City>>();

        List<City> americanCities = new List<City>();
        americanCities.Add(new City { ID = 0, Name = "Please Select A City" });
        americanCities.Add(new City { ID = 1, Name = "Boston" });
        americanCities.Add(new City { ID = 2, Name = "New York" });

        List<City> japaneseCities = new List<City>();
        japaneseCities.Add(new City { ID = 0, Name = "Please Select A City" });
        japaneseCities.Add(new City { ID = 1, Name = "Tokyo" });
        japaneseCities.Add(new City { ID = 2, Name = "Kyoto" });

        locations.Add(new Country { ID = 0, Name = "Please Select A Country" }, new List<City>());
        locations.Add(new Country { ID = 1, Name = "USA" }, americanCities);
        locations.Add(new Country { ID = 2, Name = "Japan" }, japaneseCities);
    }

    private void InitializeDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

        // Create columns
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn eventNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        eventNameColumn.HeaderText = "Event";

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn countryComboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        countryComboBox.Name = "Country";
        countryComboBox.HeaderText = "Country";
        countryComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        countryComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        foreach (Country country in locations.Keys)
        {
            countryComboBox.Items.Add(country);
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cityComboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cityComboBox.Name = "City";
        cityComboBox.HeaderText = "City";
        cityComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        cityComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(eventNameColumn);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(countryComboBox);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cityComboBox);
    }

    // Triggers when a column enters edit mode (new value not yet assigned).
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs args)
    {
        // we only want to change the city box if a country value is changed
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Country"].Index)
        {
            ComboBox countryBox = args.Control as ComboBox;
            countryBox.SelectedIndexChanged += countryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
    }

    private void countryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cityCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["City"].Index] as
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        cityCell.Items.Clear();
        foreach (City city in locations[box.SelectedItem as Country])
        {
            cityCell.Items.Add(city);
        }

        if (cityCell.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            cityCell.Value = cityCell.Items[0];
        }

        // Remove event handler to prevent memory leak
        box.SelectedIndexChanged -= countryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Denjamin 
i comeback and i am waiting your Example

Comment: @mohammedsameeh I apologize for not finding a way to make databinding work, but it's pretty tricky because you need to dynamically assign the city combobox as the data binds. You can do this with virtual mode, but the event can only be fired if the column is unbound. One work around is to create hidden columns that are bound to the actual data and make some visible unbound columns  to show the dropdowns (just use events like EditingControlShowing to update the hidden databound columns.